# Can we orchestrate Matillion Data Loader in Matillion Designer?

Tags: etl, dataloader, matillion

Suppose we have a batch data loader and i want to orchestrate that in Matillion Designer so can I do it? I did check the documentation no information found. Just had a thought that can we use APIs for this purpose. If yes how to use APIs?